# ¿Cómo mejorar un método en un modelo en rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo dos modelos Cliente y Transaccion

```
class Cliente < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :transacciones

end
```

y

```
class Transaccion < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :cliente

    def self.saldo
        saldo = 0
        all.each do |transa|
            if transa.resultado == 'G'
                saldo += transa.inversion.to_f * transa.porcentaje.to_f / 100
            elsif transa.resultado == 'P'
                saldo -= transa.inversion
            end
        end
        saldo
    end

end
```

El modelo Transaccion tiene los atributos:

**inversion**: entero que contiene un monto

**resultado**: con uno de tres valores posibles:
'G' significa que se ganó la transaccion
'P' significa que se perdió la transaccion
'E' significa que se empató la transaccion

**porcentaje**: que contiene el porcentaje en un entero, por ejemplo 88% sería 88, por supuesto el porcentaje varía.

Para obtener el saldo de un cliente debo sumar todas las transacciones ganadas del cliente, que sería (`inversion * porcentaje / 100`) y si pierde debo restar todas las transacciones perdidas del cliente.

Las asociaciones ya las resolví con el belongs_to y el has_many.

Hice el método `saldo` en el modelo `Transaccion` pero no me convence tener que hacer una interacción por toda la tabla de transacciones asociadas al cliente.

Debe de haber una mejor forma de programar esto, esa es la ayuda que necesito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes resolverlo en una sentencia de SQL, dejando todo el trabajo a la base de datos, por ejemplo, con el uso de `CASE`:

```
class Transaccion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cliente

  def.saldo
    sum(<<~SQL.squish)
      CASE
        WHEN resultado = "G" THEN inversion * porcentaje / 100
        WHEN resultado = "P" THEN inversion * -1
        ELSE 0
      END
    SQL
  end
end

class Cliente < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :transaciones

  def saldo
    transacciones.saldo
  end
end
```

El método anterior generaría solo un *query* en el que te dará como resultado el saldo; ejemplo:

```
Cliente.find(1).saldo
# SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN resultado = "G" THEN inversion * porcentaje / 100 WHEN resultado = "P" THEN inversion * -1 ELSE 0 END) FROM transacciones WHERE cliente_id = 1
#=> 1000
```

El uso de `CASE` es compatible con las principales bases de datos, pero si no quieres utilizarlo, podrías optar por usar 2 *queries*, por ejemplo:

```
class Cliente < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :transaciones

  def saldo
    saldo_ganadas - saldo_perdidas
  end

  private

  def saldo_ganadas
    transacciones.ganadas.sum("inversion * porcentaje / 100")
  end

  def saldo_perdidas
    transacciones.perdidas.sum(:inversion)
  end
end

class Transaccion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cliente

  scope :ganadas,  -> {where(resultado: 'G')}
  scope :perdidas, -> {where(resultado: 'P')}
end
```

El uso es el mismo:

```
Cliente.find(1).saldo
# SELECT SUM(inversion * porcentaje / 100) FROM transacciones WHERE cliente_id = 1 AND resultado == "G"
# SELECT SUM(inversion) FROM transacciones WHERE cliente_id = 1 AND resultado == "P"
#=> 1000
```

El ejemplo anterior podría considerarse más expresivo, aunque un poco menos eficiente, que tanto te afectará dependerá del tamaño de la tabla en la base de datos.

Comment: Gerry, me voy por el case, para dejar la carga del trabajo a la BD. La suma la hace bien, pero no resta, estoy probando diferentes combinaciones y no logro que reste, ¿tienes alguna idea?

Comment: @Developer ¿Sí pusiste el `* -1`?, ¿podrías compartir el ejemplo con el que estás probando?

Comment: Puse exactamente tu código, finalmente nos fuimos por el otro ejemplo